# sort Realm data in a tableView alphabetically by section Swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview, sorting, realm

I sorted my Realm's data alphabetically.

But I want to show it in my table view like the Contact list in the built-in iPhone apps with different sections from A to Z.

What I should do?

---

MainViewController:

```
    class MainVC: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var contact_tableview: UITableView!

    let realm = try! Realm()

    var ContactList: Results<ContactObjectss> {
        get {
//            return realm.objects(ContactObjectss.self)
            return realm.objects(ContactObjectss.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "first_name", ascending: true)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =
            [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "IRANSansWeb-Medium", size: 17)!]
        contact_tableview.delegate = self
        contact_tableview.dataSource = self    
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return ContactList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactCell") as! ContactCell
        let item = ContactList[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblName!.text = item.first_name
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let ContactV = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewContact") as! ContactInfoVC
        navigationController?.pushViewController(ContactV, animated: true)
        ContactV.ContactID = ContactList[indexPath.row]
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        contact_tableview.reloadData()
        // to reload selected cell
    }

}
```

ContactObjectss:

```
class ContactObjectss : Object {
    dynamic var id:Int = 0
    dynamic var first_name = ""
    dynamic var last_name = ""
    dynamic var work_email = ""
    dynamic var personal_email = ""
    dynamic var contact_picture = ""
    dynamic var mobile_number = ""
    dynamic var home_number = ""
    dynamic var isFavorite = false
    dynamic var Notes = ""
    dynamic var picture : NSData?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by making 26 sections(one for each letter of the alphabet), and then calculate the amount of `ContactObjects` per section.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 26 // letters of the alphabet
}
```

I assume your ContactObjects are sorted alphabetically according to their first name, if they are not just replace `first_name` with `last_name`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let sectionLetter = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z".components(separatedBy: ",")[section-1]
        let contactsWithLetter = ContactList.filter {String($0.first_name.lowercased()[$0.first_name.startIndex]) == sectionLetter} //had to use the startIndex thing because apparently $0.first_name is an inout property and therefore you can't just get it's characters
        return contactsWithLetter.count
    }
```

Comment: An Error Occurred bro : fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: could you try replacing `[section-1]` with `[section]` ? maybe the sections start at 0 instead of 1.